# Excel sorting and ranking from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a spreadsheet for my uncles hockey league. It has a separate worksheet for each of five teams and an additional sheet listing the team and player rankings. Jüri Ruut was a great help in getting the data for the players sorted out, but I need to rank the teams by "points" and then by "goals for" if they have the same amount of points.

I have column A set up with ranks 1-5. Column I has the teams "points" and column J lists the teams "goals for". So, basically:

```
 A          B             I         J
Rank   SortedRank   ~   Points   GoalsFor
```

In column B, I have the following formula:

```
 =IF(I2=I1,B1,A2)
```

Is there an easy way to modify this formula to achieve what I want? My thought was that if the original IF statement was true, then I would look to see who had more goals. I was trying to modify the [value_if_true] to another IF statement, but cannot get it to work. Something like:

```
=IF(I5=I4,IF(J4>J5,B4,A5),A5)
```

Am I even barking up the right tree here?

As always, I hope this is coherent and understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the points slightly (or create a helper column)

points would be `CalculatedPoints+(GoalsFor/1000)`
(I am assuming a team will never get more than 999 *GoalsFor*)

This way, the resulting list would look something like this

```
3.005
3.003
1.001
```

and teams with the same calculated points would then be split by the *GoalsFor*, and the `=RANK` function could easily rank the teams

Comment: Thank you for the input. Juri Root actually updated his answer to my last question with a way to solve this one as well. I do appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know / don't like the `Rank()` function, it is explained with some alternatives on [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Rank.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping to do it via the IF command, but I take it I WAS barking up the wrong tree. I will read your link after a nap. A lack of sleep is making it nearly impossible to concentrate.